# Getting object from iterator

Tags: c++, function, set

I want to get object from `set<Node>` but I think my function gives me copy of this object. How to fix it?

```
Node findByNum(int n){
    for (set<Node>::iterator it = this->children.begin();it != this->children.end(); it++){
        if ((*it).num == n){
            return (*it);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to fix it is to make your function return a reference:

```
Node& findByNum(int n)
```

You need to make sure that the node stays in the set for as long as you use a reference to it.

Comment: Inserting / deleting from `set` invalidates neither iterators nor references (cf [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert)). Working with `set<Node*>` (including smart pointers) is pointless.

Comment: @m8mble: indeed. set<unique_ptr<Node>> is still meaningful if you don't want copying to occur at all (or if Node is not copyable). It just needs a custom comparator so that it doesn't compare pointers.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct either. You can build `set`s of non-copyable types using [`set::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace).

Comment: @m8mble: indeed again :)

Answer (score 0):

Return an `iterator` instead of value or reference. You may also use `std::find_if`:

```
set<Node>::iterator Node findByNum(const int n){
    return std::find_if(children.begin(),children.end(),[n](const Node& item){
        return item.num==n;
    });
}
```

You may use it like this:

```
auto it_5=findByNum(5);
std::cout << it_5->n;
```

Be aware of [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return a reference, it's a bad option if you don't find your object.
Keeping your original code, here is a possible solution:

```
set<Node>::iterator findByNum(int n)
{
    for (set<Node>::iterator it = this->children.begin(); it != this->children.end(); ++it)
    {
        if ((*it).num == n)
            return it;
    }
    return this->children.end();
}
```

@Human answer seems also nice.